# How to get results from a Delphi function called by Lua

Tags: delphi, lua, return

I am creating a function in Delphi to be able to use it with Lua.
I have managed to create a procedure (or a function without taking results) and it works perfect.
The problem is that now I want to get results of that function (not a procedure anymore) from Delphi into Lua.
I've read some codes out there but couldn't make it work.

My function looks like this:

```
function TLuaScripter.getsetting(LuaState: TLuaState):TluaState;
var
path,stri: string; i:integer;
begin           //getsetting('Targeting/TargetingEnabled')

 path := Lua_ToString(LuaState, 1); //we get the string 'Targeting/..." 

 Lua_Pop(LuaState,1); //we put it in stack (so we can clean it)

 stri:= tree.GETsetting(path); //this function gets, for example "No"

 lua_pushlstring(LuaState,Pansichar(ansistring(stri)),length(stri)); //I pass it to the lua stack

 //showmessage(Lua_ToString(LuaState,1));--> this shows the result I need in a msgbox

 result:= LuaState;
end;
```

so now if I use in my Lua Console

```
getsetting('Targeting/TargetingEnabled')
```

I am able to get the result in a msgbox (uncommenting the "Showmessage...") but that function doesn't return anything in Lua! If I write

```
print(getsetting('Targeting/TargetingEnabled'))
```

I get a Nil value in Lua.

Comment: You should register a function of type `lua_CFunction` which returns number of results pushed into stack.  So, change return type to `Integer` and properly set the returning value `result:=1;`.  BTW, cleaning the stack by `lua_pop` is optional.

Comment: Example of proper function declaration: `function getsetting(L: Plua_State): Integer; cdecl;`

Comment: I've done the following:
-Changed return type from TLuaState to Integer.
-Changed result value to 1.
-Also I have deleted the lua_pop as you said

It is working now just like that, but it didn't work with the "cdecl" in the function. Why is it needed?

And about the "lua_CFunction", why do we need this if I can actually print the value like "print(getsetting(...))"?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Only functions conformed to `lua_CFunction` are possible to be available from Lua code.  Please show your code where you are registering your function `TLuaScripter.getsetting`.

Comment: no problem, it's okay since now it's working properly.
A lot of thanks!

Comment: Please add an answer to this question with what changes you made to get it to work and mark it as accepted.  It is perfectly ok to answer your own question.

Comment: @TobyAllen oh sorry, didn't know that, oks then :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work perfect with this. We have just added the result as integer and "result:=1"

```
function TLuaScripter.getsetting(LuaState: TLuaState): integer;
var
  path,stri: string;
  i: integer;
begin           //getsetting('Targeting/TargetingEnabled')
  path := Lua_ToString(LuaState, 1);
  stri:= tree.GETsetting(path);
  lua_pushlstring(LuaState,Pansichar(ansistring(stri)),length(stri));
  result:= 1;
end;
```